# Data Layer Convention

Tags: swagger, google-tag-manager, jsonschema, google-datalayer, tealium

I am currectly defining a data layer definition/convention that is to be used at a large oranisation.
So every time someone is defining new tags, collect some sort of information from a web page, should follow the convention.
It covers variable naming, values, type description and when to use.
The convention is later to be used with GTM/Tealium iQ but it should be tool agnostic.

What is the best way, from a technical perspective, to define the data layer schema? I am thinking if swagger of json-schema. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It's important to define your data layer in a way in which works for your organisation. That said, the best data layers have an easy to understand naming convention, are generally not nested and they contain good quality data.

A good tag manager will be able to read your data layer in whatever format you would like, whether this is out of the box or a converter which runs before tag execution.

Here is Tealium's best practice:

https://community.tealiumiq.com/t5/Data-Layer/Data-Layer-Best-Practices/ta-p/15987